# Applet esta obsoleto, que alternativa tengo?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy en un curso virtual del gobierno para aprender java, el primer ejercicio que nos piden hacer una aplicación sencilla en Applet, como sabrán applet ya no funciona fue retirado del lenguaje, me gustaría si puedo hacer esa misma aplicación de alguna otra forma y poder completar el curso.

la aplicación[image: muestra de como debe verse la ventana una vez ejecutada] es un simple ventana que cambia el color de la fuente del titulo "Servicio Nacional de Aprendizaje" a tres colores diferentes como se muestra en las imágenes adjuntas

acá esta el código de la aplicación:
estoy usando NetBeans

```
    package primerapplet;
import java.awt.Color;
public class formApplet extends javax.swing.JApplet {

@Override
public void init() {

    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    jLabel1.setText("Servicio Nacional de Aprendizaje");

    jButton1.setText("Amarillo");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Azul");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("Rojo");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(89, 89, 89)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 66, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(101, 101, 101)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(45, 45, 45)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3))
            .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setForeground(Color.blue);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setForeground(Color.yellow);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setForeground(Color.red);
}                                        


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: No me explico cómo es que tienen un curso disponible de applets desde que los navegadores no lo soportan desde hace más de 5 años...

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste reemplazar donde dice JApplet por un JFrame?

Comment: @padaleiana es un curso que da el go ier o seguro no le dan mucha cabeza a actualizarlo pero da certificados que sirven a Ninel nacional y a veces internacional así que suelen ser una buena herramienta

Comment: Java solía llevar un ejecutable appletviewer.exe para ver applets, sin necesidad de navegador. La versión java 8 lo tiene. La 11 yo creo que ya no. Puedes probar a bajarte una version 8 de java y visualizar el applet con este ejecutable.